# sunspot callback after_commit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Can anybody suggest is it possible with sunspot to have a callback like **after_commit** or **after reindex**.

I want cache facets in user session and reload them when something changed.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ActiveRecord` you may hook into `after_save` of your Model instead of hooking into sunspot. It does [the same](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb#88). Just ensure you are defining the hook after the `searchable` definition to get re-indexed data from Solr.

Comment: but how about reindexing from command like like **rake sunspot:solr:reindex** ? It does not trigger after_save - Am I right?

Comment: Nope. But you can write you own rake tasks to trigger sunspot:reindex and cache invalidation afterwards.